# iOS 10.1 and Xcode 8 issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

Just installed iOS 10.1 (non beta) today, as well as the latest (non-beta) version of Xcode via the App Store and am encountering the following error:

[image]

My Xcode version:

[image]

Any and all suggestions would be welcome! Anyone else running into this?

Comment: you can find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226916/xcode-app-running-issue

Comment: The solution is to update Xcode, just remember that for some reason Xcode updates notifications not always show up in the App Store, so you just go and search for it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here is my quick,temporary solution for XCode 11+ release,
Download the file
[iOS 14.1 build from Xcode 12.1](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FM6o-UggTiCoCA06UgqY3u1r0Zd0PW8M?usp=sharing)

1. Close the Xcode first
2. Download the 10.1 / 10.2 / 10.3 / 11.4 / 14.0 / 14.1 or all folders from gDrive
3. Copy the extracted **10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 11.4, 14.0, 14.1+** folders to this directory
   ***/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport***
4. Open Xcode again and wait to sync
5. Run on iOS **10.1~14.1** devices - Voilà

Comment: Wow that works. Thank you so much. If you didn't answer 3 hours ago. I will be downloading XCode 8.1 GM with my ultra slow connection (1.5 mbps).

Comment: yeah, that was really painful for me too,
happy to know that it's not same for you :)

Comment: so the whole update is only to add this 15mb dir?? Apple is so funny

Comment: sort of :3
I was also thinking about that

Comment: Does this work for other iOS 10 releases? For example, is there a 10.1.1 (14B100) build that I could find somewhere to help me out until I can download XCode 8.1?

Comment: @HélèneMartin I've added the iOS 10.2 build files, so it should work on 10.1.1 :)

Comment: Are these files you pulled from an XCode install or is there a generic place to get developer disk images?

Comment: man you saved me a day of downloading , thank you so much . i hate slow internet .

Comment: I think I'll need to come here every time I update my phone :)

Comment: @Neuber - Not so funny, more like irritating. So we as developers have to run GM and beta software (as in Xcode 8.1 etc) in order to connect to devices with production software on it (aka iOS 10.2.1) The Xcode AppStore release is still 8.0 - Not nice

Answer (score 10):

iOS 10.1 support wasn't added until Xcode 8.1 which is currently available as a GM release from https://developer.apple.com/download/

Comment: such Apple...such suit yourself