# Xcode App Running Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

I just updated my iPhone 5 to iOS version 10.1. When I tried to run the app that I'm developing on my device I got the following error from Xcode:

"Could not locate device support files. 
This iPhone 5 (Model A1429) is running iOS 10.1 (14B72), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode."

I have the latest version of Xcode i.e. 8.0 (I just double checked to see if there are any available updates). I cannot set the deployment target higher than 10.0 either.

What do I need to do? Is there a way to downgrade my device? When there is an update in the future should I wait until the version is released on Xcode?

Comment: If you go to https://developer.apple.com/download/ , you should be able to get at the Xcode 8.1 GM, which I'm guessing is about the only way you'll be able to get the iOS 10.1 SDK at this point. **EDIT** I just noticed that 8.1 GM only provides the iOS 10.1 *beta* SDK, not the production release.

Comment: [link to gist of a possible solution](https://gist.github.com/steipete/d9b44d8e9f341e81414e86d7ff8fb62d)

Comment: How could Apple let this happen???  This seems like an obvious miss.  The non-beta OS version should never get ahead of the non-beta SDK version.  I mean, I know they hate us 3rd party developers from the very pits of their soul, but could they maybe make their contempt not so obvious???

Comment: UPDATE: your xcode and macOS You can now download Xcode 8.1 from the Mac App Store. This version includes the latest macOS SDKs for building apps that use the all-new Touch Bar on the new MacBook Pro. To develop apps for the Touch Bar, you’ll need a Mac running Xcode 8.1 on macOS Sierra 10.12.1 (12B2657) or later.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually your iOS version still fresh and xCode SDK still in beta

you can download the beta SDK's from here
[xCode 10.1 beta SDK download](https://developer.apple.com/download/)

UPDATE:
Now apple have updated Xcode to 8.1 which include the SDK for 10.1, and you can download it from app store.

Comment: Get me in great trouble on the development  after upgrading to 10.1  .

Answer (score 4):

**Xcode 8.1 is now available**

[Download link.](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12)

Note from Apple News:

> You can now download Xcode 8.1 from the Mac App Store. This version includes the latest macOS SDKs for building apps that use the all-new Touch Bar on the new MacBook Pro. To develop apps for the Touch Bar, you’ll need a Mac running Xcode 8.1 on macOS Sierra 10.12.1 (12B2657) or later.

Comment: Yeah I just did. It is now working properly on my iPhone. So apparently we need to wait 3 days or so for Xcode to catch up with the new iOS version.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option in order to do not download full xcode, you need to download files from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933303/use-xcode-7-3-1-with-ios-10-1-14b67-device) topic (in Update comment)

Then you need to copy 10.1 (14B65) folder to
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/

so the full path will look like:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.1 (14B65)
with two files in it: DeveloperDiskImage.dmg.signature and DeveloperDiskImage.dmg

It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Updates between iOS and macOS are independent though if you are developer they are not because iOS and Xcode have to match. In my case my iOS upgraded automatically but my Xcode did not, and could not, because I had postponed the upgrade of my macOS (laziness). After I upgraded my macOS my Xcode could also upgrade to the right version suitable for the iOS version on my iPad and everything worked fine again.